# How to zoom in on picture in Apple Keynote

Tags: keynote

I've been trying to figure out how to slowly zoom in or ease in on a picture in keynote. I would like the effect to be something like this -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6af4AQG-r4E (go to 0:55 seconds). I've built a keynote presentation in a similar layout to what you see in the video. Additionally, the video also has effects where the image pans sideways. Is it possible to do any of these effects in keynote?

Comment: Which platform? macOS or iOS?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the scale animation. If you are using iOS, you can add this by taping the image, tapping the animate button, tapping add action button, and selecting the “scale” animation. To change the duration and scale of the animation, tap the image again, tap animate, tap on the scale animation you just added twice, and a menu should appear, giving you more settings for your animation.